# test class for apex class contains external object

Tags: unit-test

how to write test class for the apex class contains external object

code snippet!!!

```
Public Class AliasAddressController {
Public Address__x addr{get;set;}
Public List<Address__x> Adrlst{get;set;}
Public AliasAddressController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    addr = new Address__x();
    Address__x adr = new Address__x ();
    addr= (Address__x)controller.getRecord();
    adr= [Select SAID__c,PrincipalSAID__c from Address__x where id=:addr.id];
    Adrlst=new list<Address__x>();
     Adrlst=[Select id,SAID__c from Address__x where PrincipalSAID__c=:adr.SAID__c AND Active__c =0];
        }
        }



@isTest
public class AliasAddressControllerTest {
    static TestMethod void TestAliasAddress()
    {
        test.startTest();
        Address__x mockedRequest = new Address__x ();
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(mockedRequest);
        AliasAddressController Cont=new AliasAddressController(sc);
        PageReference pageRef = Page.AliasAddress;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(mockedRequest.Id));
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing with your test class? Can you share the issue and test class code you have so the community can suggest better?

Comment: @isTest
public class AliasAddressControllerTest {
    static TestMethod void TestAliasAddress()
    {
        test.startTest();
        Address__x mockedRequest = new Address__x ();
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(mockedRequest);
        AliasAddressController Cont=new AliasAddressController(sc);
        PageReference pageRef = Page.AliasAddress;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(mockedRequest.Id));
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        test.stopTest();
            
    }
}

Comment: List has no rows of assignment ..

Comment: it is better if you add your test class in your question instead of adding as comment. it will be easy to understand.

Comment: http://grahambarnard.com/development/2016/02/08/mocking-external-objects/ - may give you some ideas

Answer (score 0):

You have created record for Address__x in the test class but not inserted,

```
Address__x mockedRequest = new Address__x ();
```

so there will be no id for **mockedRequest**